# Java + java.net.UnknownHostException

Tags: java

I have tried adding proxy, nonProxyHost etc. in Eclipse but not able to pass through this error. I also read lot of pages around `java.net.UnknownHostException` but no luck. Below is the snippet and exception.

```
URL url = new URL("https://xyz.com/Something");
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection)connection;
ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
OutputStream out = httpConn.getOutputStream(); //Fails with
//Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: xyz.com
```

Full stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.UnknownHostException: xyz.com
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)
```

I have tried setting below proxies through code:

```
System.setProperty("useDefaultWebProxy", "true");
System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "my_proxy_server");
System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "8080");
System.setProperty("https.nonProxyHosts", "xyz.com");
```

Also, in Eclipse I have set proxy and proxy bypass in `Window -> Preferences -> General -> Network Connection`

Comment: How are you settings the proxy? Post all the things that you have already tried. That will help us help you.

Comment: @Nikhil, trace communication with host using ICMP message i.e ping, telnet, traceroute.

Comment: @Subir - I have updated my original post with what options I have tried.

Comment: @AlpeshGediya - You mean execute "trace xyz.com" or "ping xyz.com" in command line. I tried but it does not work, please let me know if you mean something else.

Comment: @Nikhil if you can't ping it from that machine than you won't be able to use Java to open a http connection.

Comment: @Pedantic - Right, but usually we provide URL like http://www.google.com in Java code and if you try "ping www.google.com" it also does not work in command prompt. I suspect its with proxy setting, but not sure what exactly I am missing here.